# Postgres service started, but can't connect. Nothing listening on port 5432

Tags: postgresql

I don't know how this happened, but my postgres server (9.6.2) has stopped working locally.  I seem to be able to start it up, and stop it using:
`brew services start postgresql` and `brew services start postgresql` but when I try to connect using psql I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the
server running locally and accepting    connections on Unix domain
socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I try to see if anything is listening on port 5432 using `lsof -i :5432` I get nothing.

Looked at other posts that say check the `pg_hba.conf` file, which I did, but doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: try runing `pg_ctl start`

Comment: here's the error I'm getting with that command:
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

Comment: then `psql -D PGDATA` where PGDADA is the directory with data

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL database log for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling postgres via homebrew.  That by itself didn't do enough.  I had to kill my data directory to get this to work (i.e. `rm -rf /path/to/my/data/directory`) and then rebuild it using `initdb`.

This solution obviously only works if you don't care about keeping your data (in my case, it was just data for my dev environment, so I didn't).  If you do want to save a copy of your data, I you'd have to come up with something else.